# How to contain derived types in a vector?

Tags: c++, pointers, vector

I am making a game in C++ and I want my Game class to hold all of the GameObjects. It has a vector of the abstract base GameObject class, but in order for it to hold derived types it must be a vector of pointers to GameObjects:

```
// Game.h
class Game {
private:
    std::vector<GameObject*> gameObjects;
public:
    void addGameObject(GameObject* gameObject) {
        gameObjects.push_back(gameObject);
    }
}
```

The problem that arises happens when I want to add GameObjects to the vector. When I pass in a pointer to addGameObject, the pointer becomes NULL in the other scope. So I would like for the pointer to be stored in the vector, but not become NULL immediately afterwards. I do not know how I could get around this problem. Any ideas?

Edit: Thank you all for commenting. I have used C++ for a while now but I am new to using pointers and do not fully understand them yet. I knew that you needed to use them to create the vector that held the derived objects. I guess I need to research pointers a lot more.

Comment: Why does the pointer become NULL in the other scope? Show that code please.

Comment: The issue is elsewhere. The behaviour you have described has nothing to do with `vector::push_back`.

Comment: This doesn't make sense.  Pointers are passed by-value and there is nothing the `addGameObject` function can do to make the original pointer `NULL`.  Modern C++ should probably use smart pointers instead, anyway.

Comment: This vaguely sounds like a design the designer stopped understanding.

Comment: Unless by 'NULL' they actually mean 'goes out of scope and is destroyed, creating an invalid pointer', in which case they need to learn about both `new` and `smart_ptr`.

Comment: I guess you have bungled your ownership semantics. Who owns those `GameObjects`, and is on the hook for `delete`-ing them?

Answer (score 1):

> *"The problem that arises happens when I want to add GameObjects to the vector. When I pass in a pointer to addGameObject, the pointer becomes NULL in the other scope."*

I can't tell why these pointers *become `NULL` in the other scope*, as you don't mentioned enough context to proove this.

But I think the better choice seems to be using a [smart pointer](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory) like this

```
// Game.h
class Game {
private:
    std::vector<std::shared_ptr<GameObject>> gameObjects;
public:
    void addGameObject(std::shared_ptr<GameObject> gameObject) {
        gameObjects.push_back(gameObject);
    }
}
```

There are more choices for smart pointers, depending on your actual use cases for them, namely `std::unique_ptr<GameObject>` or `std::weak_ptr<GameObject>`.

`std::shared_ptr<GameObject>` (or the other mentioned smart pointer variants) should serve well for instances derived from `GameObject` class like e.g.

```
class Player : public GameObject {
    // ...
};
```

This would manage references to your `GameObject` instance, as they are in use, or being owned in any scope.

Comment: Why no `std::move`? Also, `std::unique_ptr` can conceivably be more appropriate there, though we cnnot really tell.

Comment: @Deduplicator _"though we cannot really tell."_ Yeah. At least I have mentioned the other (main) available smart pointer variants. What the OP actually needs, completely depends on the (not further explained) semantics.